# Alignment issue of floating html divs

Tags: javascript, css, html

I created two divs in my html web page as follows -

```
<div style="float:left">image here</div>
<div style="float:right">small images and medium size text content here</div>
```

What I intend to do is left-right alignment of these two divs. But the problem is each div taking half the width of the container, as a result there are some spaces at right of left side div and  before the right side div, as usually right side div started from the middle of the container width.

I want that right side div content will be just at the right of left div with no spaces, but it's not appearing. So still problem is not solved by Google master yet.

A approach I took is I removed float styles from both of these divs and gave a `float:left` style to the image and things are good that image appearing at left and content at right (right side div content) but problem is when large content are there, content goes below the image too starting from right side which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="float:left">image here</div>
<div >small images and medium size text content here</div>
```

Comment: yes there is no spaces at right side of left div but as i said large text content still going below the image starting from right side div. i will check other answers soon.

Comment: Please don't post "try this" answers.  They don't explain what the problem is or how "this" fixes it, so they don't help anyone in the future.

Comment: I assume he is smart enough to see that I removed 3 words from his original code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the div's have a margin or padding already set due to a parent tag. If it does remove it by specifying the below style to the div tag

```
style="padding: 0px !important;"
```

OR

```
style="margin: 0px !important;"
```

You can also give specific width to the divs in percentage like `style="width: 30%;"`

After this specify the `float: left` style for both the divs as you want them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        .clearfix:after { content:""; display:table; clear:both; }
        .clearfix > div { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; width: 50%; vertical-align:top }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div class="wall-data clearfix">

        <div style="float:left;">
            <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank" class="wall-media-link">
            <img class="wall-picture" src="http://localhost/joomla_ext/modules/mod_mymodule/tmpl/images/picture.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

        <div style="float:right">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" >
                <img  class="wall-avatar" src="http://localhost/joomla_ext/modules/mod_mymodule/tmpl/images/profile.png" /> </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="wall-message-from" target="_blank">Name Here</a>

            <div>Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte  Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old CharlotteTen-year-old Charlotte Ten-year-old CharlotteTen-year-old Charlotte    </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can remove the box-sizing if you remove the border style

Comment: it's look like working but whole container width decreased half!

Comment: my whole content container width was 100%, after implementing your code i am seeing whole content width decreased to look like 50%

Comment: ok guys i created a jsfiddle with codes here http://jsfiddle.net/mn9e3ytL/ look from begining, things not appearing well

Comment: where is badly formatted? why not put a online image url for img source.Try to solve what i want reading all comments and answers here

Comment: its better if we see the whole page layout because the code i sent, works, so you have obviously not copied it right or embedded it in the wrong place. use tools like firebug or web inspector

Comment: if you look at jsfiddle code i am seeing right side div being at bottom, so start with it.

Comment: ar, sounds like you need to add vertical-align: top. see the updated code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62525/discussion-between-dev-m-and-christian).

Comment: I was wanting to avoid giving width to these divs as per requirements, if things not resolved then i may think for width

Comment: Also i am thinking table based layout, what about that?

Answer (score 0):

When an Element is `float`ed, it goes out of the normal document flow, suspending itself in the direction you're trying to `float:left;` or `float:right;`. If you are using a block level Element, like a `<div>` and there is another block level Element before your `<div>`, then your `float`ed Element will do as usual, creating a line break after the block level Element which is before your `<div>`. If a `float`ed Element is within another Element, the content (with respect to normal block level rules and the content Elements' `float`) within the Parent Element wraps to the opposite side of your `float`, while what you `float`ed pushes itself all the way against the Parent Element's padding in the direction of the `float`. So, `float`ing respects padding, borders, and margins. Also, you should know that `height` does not include padding, borders, or margins. You need to factor them in until CSS3's `box-sizing` becomes widespread. You should use CSS instead of the HTML style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to set div height.If the height is same,it won't go down to left side div.

```
<html>
<div style="float:left;border:1px solid black;height:300px">small images and medium size text content here</div>
<div style="border:1px solid black;height:300px">image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/>image hereawef<br/></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Container `<div>`, which you did not add, would have to be `602px`+`padding`+`margins`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited your JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mn9e3ytL/1/

You needed to close a div before the text.

```
<img class="wall-picture" src="http://localhost/joomla_ext/modules/mod_mymodule/tmpl/images/picture.jpg" /> </a>
</DIV>
<div style="float:right">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" >
```

Comment: what i didn't give closing </div> ?, anyway put a image and see text going below the first div. It's look like complicated as i thought, so i am trying giving % width to both these divs.

Comment: @dev-m I just don't understand what is not working... :(